# Flutter- printing package causing error in windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

```
/C:/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.11.0/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart:173:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'size'.
          size:
          ^^^^
/D:/downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:24:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const ViewConfiguration({
```

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZa35.png)

this is package ling: https://pub.dev/packages/printing

When I remove the package the error gone ,so the error is 100% from printing package.

Answer (score 1):

You will be using the beta or master branch.
This is an upcoming issue relating to dynamic view sizing within the framework.There has been talk that this will be reversed and although this did look like to be the case, the latest master build again has the issue that is evident in beta builds.

See the following github threads for further information and potential ways to solve:

[Pdf package thread discussing the issue](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/pull/1551)

[The flutter framework thread discussing the underlying changes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/138648#discussion_r1414289667)

Comment: Thank you , actually I have solved this error by changing the beta branch  to stable branch .